# Using Union tool in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, java, union

I am currently working with the Union tool of ArcObjects but I do not know how to properly pass the input_features to the union object. I´ve tried several methods but all throw an Automation Exception (0x80004005 - Unspecified Error). I could not find a single sample for the Union tool in Java.

```
   GeoProcessor geoProcessor = null;
   try {
        geoProcessor = new GeoProcessor();
        geoProcessor.setOverwriteOutput(true);
        // Get featureclass objects of both shapes
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.openFromFile("C:\\test", 0);
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace) workspace;
        IFeatureClass fc1 = featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass("a.shp");
        IFeatureClass fc2 = featureWorkspace.openFeatureClass("b.shp");
        // Create IGPValueTableObject and and add featureclasses
        IGpValueTableObject gpvtObject = new GpValueTableObject();
        gpvtObject.setColumns(2);
        gpvtObject.setRow(0, fc1);
        gpvtObject.setValue(0, 1, 1);
        gpvtObject.setRow(1, fc2);
        gpvtObject.setValue(1, 1, 2);
        /*
         * Also tried this:
         * gpvtObject.addRow(fc1);
         * gpvtObject.addRow(fc2);
        */
        Union union = new Union();
        union.setInFeatures(gpvtObject);
        union.setOutFeatureClass("C:\\test\\union.shp");
        geoProcessor.execute(union, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the input features are specified as follows:

"X #;Y #;Z #;"

Where X, Y, and Z are either a layer or a path to a feature class and '#' is either a number representing the rank of the feature class or '#' if the feature class has no rank.

So your input would be something like:

"C:\test\a.shp #; C:\test\b.shp #"

I found this by running Union in ArcMap and looking at the Geoprocessing Results window message which lists the input arguments.

Comment: Your answer really helped me!

I´ve tried it and if I specify my input features like this it works: 

"'X' #; 'Y' #" --- "'C:\test\a.shp' #; 'C:\test\b.shp' #"